# Does a timeout take up memory?

Tags: javascript, memory, settimeout

This question is probably trivial, but I am confused about what I should do.

Basically, I noticed that each successive timeout I call has a greater ID number. I'm sure this is just to reduce ID conflicts, but I'm worried that even though a timeout has already executed, it still exists in memory.

If a timeout function has been executed, do you need to call anything to "*delete*" it? In my code I'm doing this:

```
clearTimeout(time);// destroy previous timer?
time = setTimeout( function(){ hitup( towards );}, ms);// next execution
```

Comment: clearTimeout() is only needed to stop the event from happening in the future.

Comment: You'd need 9007199254740991 timeouts in order to cause any conflict.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How exactly a Javascript engine implements timerID value storage is entirely implementation dependent.  They probably uses some sort of map or hashtable since that's a classic storage mechanism for sparse (non-sequential) values like this.

Previously fired or cleared timers will not still be active or using memory.  You do not need to call anything to delete a timer.

The code you showed:

```
clearTimeout(time);// destroy previous timer?
time = setTimeout( function(){ hitup( towards );}, ms);// next execution
```

is sometimes still useful.  If you don't yet know if the timer store in the variable `time` has actually fired and you do not want it to fire anymore and you're about to overwrite the variable where you store its ID, then it does sometimes make sense to call `clearTimeout()` in that case.  If you know the timer has fired or if you want it to fire, then there is no need to call `clearTimeout()` on it.

The system will take care of memory management here.  That is not something you have to worry about.  You only have to worry about stopping a timer if it hasn't yet fired and you don't want it to fire at its scheduled time.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was hoping. So after it has fired it is rendered pretty much useless?

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew - yes, after a `setTimeout()` has fired or is stopped manually with a `clearTimeout()`, it is cleaned up by the system.

Comment: You don't need to use `clearTimeout` for setTimeout, it's used to stop further execution and basically used with `setInterval`  which repeats the execution after a specified interval. Leave the memory management on `GC`.

Answer (score 1):

Ususally if the timeout function executed, it and it's closure will be deleted. TimeoutID autoincrement is used only for avoiding conflicts.

But in some cases the closure of timeout function can exist if it used somewere else - for example if you create another timeout function or event handler or just make reference to global object.

You don't need to call any special delete function.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the `time` variable for anything don't assign the timeout to a variable.

If you don't assign setTimeout to a variable, you can use timers indefinitely without wasting memory provided they are expirying. e.g. many timeouts with long times will use memory until they expire.

Comment: If they are in an anonymous class, and if the same variable is used to catch each successive id, I think the memory used to hold their id's will be garbage collected.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew correct. the issue would be if you used multiple variables or an array to capture timeouts in a global or a protoype / instantiated object.